# AWS elastic Beanstalk / nginx : connect() failed (111: Connection refused

Tags: node.js, amazon-web-services, express, nginx, amazon-elastic-beanstalk

I got this message

```
connect() failed (111: Connection refused
```

Here is my log:

```
-------------------------------------
/var/log/nginx/error.log
-------------------------------------
2018/10/21 06:16:33 [error] 4282#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.4.119, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/", host: "hackingdeal-env.qnyexn72ga.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com"
2018/10/21 06:16:33 [error] 4282#0: *2 connect() failed (111: Connection refused) while connecting to upstream, client: 172.31.4.119, server: , request: "GET /favicon.ico HTTP/1.1", upstream: "http://127.0.0.1:8081/favicon.ico", host: "hackingdeal-env.qnyexn72ga.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com", referrer: "http://hackingdeal-env.qnyexn72ga.ap-northeast-2.elasticbeanstalk.com/"
```

I am using nodejs/express Elastic Beanstalk env.

I have one nginx related file in

```
.ebextensions/nginx/conf.d/proxy.conf
```

Upper file contains:

```
client_max_body_size 50M;
```

Whenever I try to get my webpage I got 502 bad gateway.

What's wrong with my app?

Comment: Make sure your express app is up and running

Answer (score 6, accepted):

111 connection refused likely means your app isn't running on the server/port combination. Also check that the security group for your app instance (or load balancer) has an inbound rule set to allow traffic from the nginx instance

Comment: how can I allow traffic from the nginx instance??

Comment: You should have a security group for your nginx instance and your beanstalk load balancer. On the load balancer sg, add an inbound rule and select the security group of the nginx instance

Answer (score 7):

Just recording my incident here just in case it helps someone or my future self. I had a Django application that had `SECURE_SSL_REDIRECT` set to `True`. Since I had no load balancers configured to handle HTTPS traffic I was getting a timeout. Setting it to `False` fixed the issue. Couple of days wasted on that one.

Answer (score 1):

I was dealing with this error on my NodeJS application (NEXTJS). Posting this here just in case is useful for someone.

My error was thet the deploy command failed at the build step (next build), which means the Node server never restarted. For that reason nginx could not find the server. You can find this kind of errors in the `web.stdout.log`

I tested my build command locally, fixed the errors and it worked!

Comment: Same here for me for a django application. The wsgi package was not found

Answer (score 0):

Been fumbling with this for days. It's happening in my case because I am trying to use Elastic Beanstalk with a MySQL DB.

The connection is refused because you need to allow your IP address on the inbound security group.

- go to EC2 instance
- go to security groups
- select the one with description "Enable database access to Beanstalk application"
- edit the inbound rules, for type pick "MySQL/Aurora", and for source put in your IP address (if you're just in a testing phase like me).